# Code economy in a modular figure with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create with tikz a figure similar to the following capture, which I have made with a CAD program:
[image]
This is a snippet of the tikz code:

```
% Modular figure with tikz. By Jesús Álvarez Lobo ________________
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{graphicx, subfig}
    \usepackage{floatrow}   
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{document}
        \pagestyle{empty}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.05, line width=1pt]
            \draw[fill=gray!25, fill opacity=0.5]  (0,0) circle (16);
            \draw(0, 16) -- (0,48);
            \draw [fill=gray!25, fill opacity=0.5](0,56) circle (8);
            \draw(0, 64) -- (0,80);
            \draw(8, 56) -- (24,56);
            \draw(-8, 56) -- (-24,56);      
            \draw [fill=gray!25, fill opacity=0.5](0,84) circle (4);
            \draw [fill=gray!25, fill opacity=0.5](28,56) circle (4);
            \draw [fill=gray!25, fill opacity=0.5](-28,56) circle (4);
            \draw(0, 88) -- (0,96);
            \draw [fill=gray!25, fill opacity=0.5](0,98) circle (2);
            \draw(0, 100) -- (0,104);
            \draw[fill=gray!25, fill opacity=0.5] (0,105) circle (1);
            \draw(0, 106) -- (0,108);
            \draw(-1, 105) -- (-3,105);
            \draw(1, 105) -- (3,105);       
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Technically I have no problem doing all the drawing in tikz; What I ask myself is how to take advantage of the **modularity of the figure** to obtain a **great economy of code**.
As can be easily seen, the entire tree can be built by repeating the following subfigure, placing it in the proper position, rotating it if necessary, and scaling. The scale of each of these generating modules is .5 in each iteration in the tree.

```
% Modular figure with tikz. By Jesús Álvarez Lobo ________________
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfig}
\usepackage{floatrow}   
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.05, line width=1pt]
        \draw(0, 16) -- (0,48);
        \draw [fill=gray!25, fill opacity=0.5](0,56) circle (8);
        \draw(0, 64) -- (0,80);
        \draw(8, 56) -- (24,56);
        \draw(-8, 56) -- (-24,56);      
        \draw [fill=gray!25, fill opacity=0.5](0,84) circle (4);
        \draw [fill=gray!25, fill opacity=0.5](28,56) circle (4);
        \draw [fill=gray!25, fill opacity=0.5](-28,56) circle (4);  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Unlike the captured image, no color is used (grayscale only) and the circles are single lines, not rings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my attempt:

First define some commands.

```
\newcommand{\module}{%
    \draw(0, 16) -- (0,48);
    \draw [fill=gray!25, fill opacity=0.5](0,56) circle (8);
    \draw(0, 64) -- (0,80);
    \draw(8, 56) -- (24,56);
    \draw(-8, 56) -- (-24,56);      
    \draw [fill=gray!12.5](0,84) circle (4);
    \draw [fill=gray!12.5](28,56) circle (4);
    \draw [fill=gray!12.5](-28,56) circle (4);
}
```

This is the code that was provided in the question

```
\newcommand{\fourFoldSymmetry}[1]{%
    {#1}
    \begin{scope}[rotate=90]
        {#1}
        \begin{scope}[rotate=90]
            {#1}
        \begin{scope}[rotate=90]
            {#1}
        \end{scope}
        \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
}
```

This repeats something four times around the circle

```
\newcommand{\threeFoldSymmetryULR}[1]{%
{#1}
\begin{scope}[xshift=56cm, yshift=-56cm, rotate around={-90:(0, 56)}]
    {#1}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=-56cm, yshift=-56cm, rotate around={90:(0, 56)}]
        {#1}
    \end{scope}
}
\newcommand{\threeFoldSymmetryURD}[1]{%
    \begin{scope}[rotate=-90]
        \threeFoldSymmetryULR{#1}
    \end{scope}
}
\newcommand{\threeFoldSymmetryULD}[1]{%
    \begin{scope}[rotate=90]
        \threeFoldSymmetryULR{#1}
    \end{scope}
}
```

These repeat someting three times in the directions indicated, `U` for up, `L` for left, `D` for down, and `R` for right.

The diagram can then be drawn as follows:

```
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.05, line width=1pt]
        % Draw the centre circle
        \draw [fill=gray!25, fill opacity=0.5] (0, 0) circle (16);
        % Everything is rotated four times
        \fourFoldSymmetry{
        \module  % Inner layer
        % Move up to next layer and then scale by 0.5
        \begin{scope}[yshift=56cm, scale=0.5]  
            \threeFoldSymmetryULR{\module}
            \begin{scope}[xshift=56cm, scale=0.5]
                \threeFoldSymmetryURD{\module}
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[xshift=-56cm, scale=0.5]
                \threeFoldSymmetryULD{\module}
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[yshift=56cm, scale=0.5]
                \threeFoldSymmetryULR{\module}
            \end{scope}
        \end{scope}
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm sure there are more intelligent ways to do this, I simply worked out how much shift was needed each time but If you want a greater recursion depth this will be an issue. Also I think you may want to think about what you use as the base module. Notice that I removed the opacity and instead changed `gray!25` to `gray!12.5` to achieve the same colour. This is because I have overlapped circles as I think that a more intuitive base is a large circle and the three smaller circles that come off of it. There is also some overlapping of the sticks which can make some pdf viewers show parts as thicker than they actually are.
[image: the requested figure]

Comment: Thank you very much Willoughby. I am pleasantly surprised by the result. I'm starting with tikz (this is my 2nd exercise); so I will need a little time to interpret your code (although very clear, well commented and structured) and see if the overlaps you are referring to can be avoided and thus prevent some PDF viewer from offering an unwanted result. I don't think it is possible to optimize the solution further. Regarding the substitution of the degree of opacity for a lower intensity of gray, it seems to me a good idea.

Comment: I am sure that this exercise and Willoughby's beautiful solution will be useful to many people who, like me, are starting out in this exciting world of LaTeX + tikz design.

Comment: I have been wondering during the last days whether the `tree` library from tikz is perfect for these kind of images. Check [This link](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/title-graphics/) where the represented image is more or less similar, meaning that it has also sublevels within sublevels